# Python: IndexError: list index out of range with randint function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a code that asks the user if they want the program to draw rectangular patterns (if they enter the number 1) or circular patterns (if they enter number 2).

It works fine, but if the user enters the number 3 then the program randomly has to choose to draw either circular or rectangular patterns in a random place on the screen.

The only input the user has to enter after choosing (3) is how many random patterns should be drawn on the screen.

The problem is that I am getting an **error**

> "line 91, in drawSuperPattern rand_shape = shape_functs[randint(0,1)] IndexError: list index out of range".

How can I solve this? I have tried fixing it but I can't seem to solve it.

my main code:

```
import pattern

def main():

    while True:
        print("Choose a mode")
        print("1) Rectangle Pattern")
        print("2) Circle Pattern")
        print("3) Super Pattern")

        mode = int(input("Which mode do you want to play? 1, 2 or 3: "))

        pattern.setup()

        if mode == 1:
            width = int(input("Enter width for the rectangles: "))
            height = int(input("Enter height for the rectangles: "))
            offset = int(input("Enter the offset for the rectangle: "))
            count = int(input("Enter how many rectangles you'd like in the pattern: "))
            centerX, centerY = eval(input("Enter center position (x, y): "))

            pattern.drawRectanglePattern(int(centerX), int(centerY), width, height, count, offset)
        elif mode == 2:
            radius = int(input("Enter the radius for the circles: "))
            offset2 = int(input("Enter the offset for the circle: "))
            count = int(input("Enter how many circles you'd like in the pattern: "))
            centerX, centerY = eval(input("Enter center position (x, y): "))

            pattern.drawCirclePattern(int(centerX), int(centerY), radius, count, offset2)
        elif mode == 3:
            super = int(input("Enter how many super patterns you'd like: "))

            pattern.drawSuperPattern(super)

        print("Do you want to play again?")
        print("1) Yes, and keep drawings")
        print("2) Yes, and clear drawings")
        print("3) No, I am all done")

        response = int(input("Choose 1, 2, or 3: "))

        if response == 1:
            pass
        elif response == 2:
            pattern.reset()
        else:
            print("Thanks for playing!")
            break

main()
```

pattern.py code

```
import turtle
from random import choice, randint

turtle.speed('fastest')

SCREEN_WIDTH = 1000
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 800

COLORS = ["pink", "red", "purple", "black", "dark cyan", "lavender", "blue", "yellow", "dark green", "orange", "gold", "brown", "tan"]

def setup():
    turtle.screensize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT)
    turtle.speed('fastest')

def reset():
    turtle.clearscreen()

def getRandomColor():
    return choice(COLORS)

def drawRectangle(centerX, centerY, width, height):
    #turtle.goto(centerX - width/2, centerY - height/2)
    turtle.pd()
    turtle.color(getRandomColor())

    for _ in range(2):
        turtle.forward(width)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(height)
        turtle.left(90)


def drawRectanglePattern(centerX, centerY, width, height, count, offset):
    rotation = 360 / count
    turtle.pu()
    turtle.goto(centerX, centerY)

    for _ in range(count):

        turtle.pu()

        turtle.forward(offset)
        turtle.right(90+rotation/2)

        drawRectangle(centerX, centerY, width, height)

        turtle.pu()

        turtle.left(90+rotation/2)
        turtle.backward(offset)


        turtle.right(rotation)

def drawCircle(centerX, centerY, radius):

    turtle.pd()
    turtle.color(getRandomColor())
    turtle.circle(radius)


def drawCirclePattern(centerX, centerY, radius, count, offset2):
    rotation = 360 / count
    turtle.pu()
    turtle.goto(centerX, centerY)

    for _ in range(count):

        turtle.pu()

        turtle.forward(offset2)
        turtle.right(90+rotation/2)

        drawCircle(centerX, centerY, radius)


        turtle.pu()

        turtle.left(90+rotation/2)
        turtle.backward(offset2)


        turtle.right(rotation)

def drawSuperPattern(super):

    for i in range(super):

        shape_functs = [drawRectanglePattern]

        rand_shape = shape_functs[randint(0,1)]

        width = randint(0,100)
        height = randint(0,100)
        offset = randint(0,100)
        count = randint(0,100)
        centerX = randint(0,100)
        centerY = randint(0,100)

        rand_shape(int(centerX), int(centerY), width, height, count, offset)

        shape_funcs = [drawCirclePattern]
        rand_shape2 = shape_funcs[randint(0, 1)]

        offset2 = randint(0, 100)
        count = randint(0, 100)
        radius = randint(0, 100)
        centerX = randint(0, 200)
        centerY = randint(0, 200)

        rand_shape2(centerX, centerY, count, offset2, radius)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have one item in your shape_funcs list:

```
shape_functs = [drawRectanglePattern]
rand_shape = shape_functs[randint(0,1)]
```

If you try access element 0, rand_shape will set to "drawRectanglePattern" but there is no object at element 1, it is outside the bounds of your list.  If you try and access it it will error.

You could try:

```
shape_functs = [drawRectanglePattern, drawCirclePattern]
```

This will solve that error, but since drawRectanglePattern and drawCirclePattern take a different number of arguments, the code will fail when you try and call rand_shape.

A good software pattern to use here, particularly if you have lots of different shapes to choose from would use 'Inheritance'.  For your simple use case you can get away with something like:

```
randnum = randint(0, 1)
if randnum == 0:
    # set up rectangle inputs
    drawRectanglePattern(int(centerX), int(centerY), width, height, count, offset)
elif randnum == 1:
    # set up circle inputs
    drawCirclePattern(centerX, centerY, radius, count, offset2)
```

Comment: I tried it but it is not working.  I have written that code on the pattern.py module, and the program is not giving me any errors but the program is not drawing the patterns.

Comment: There was a small typo, should have read randnum = randint(0, 1) (not 1, 2).  Otherwise the code runs for me fine.

Comment: Did you add that on the main code or the pattern code? 'cause the rectangle inputs would be different from the def drawRectanglePattern.

Comment: Also, for the super pattern, the user has to only enter how many patterns must be drawn and not anything else. That is why setting up the inputs wouldn't work.